# How to make a GAE server repeat operation?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

If I want to update a cache every minute, or do something else every hour, where I should put my code (Java) ? As I think, not in the servlets. Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use cron jobs:

[Scheduled Tasks With Cron for Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron)

This is exactly what they have been designed for.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Andrei Volgin is correct, and you need to pursue the link.

However, I want to address the 'not in the servlets' part of your questions. I think you are asking from a design perspective whether the code should reside inside the servlet class. I have answered this for myself recently.

The way Crons and Tasks are implemented by GAE, the code will be called via servlets, as these are background URL calls. So, theoretically, the code can be in the servlet class itself. If you are using a framework like Spring, you will probably have one entry point servlet and your own handlers/managers/services. In this case, you can write the code in the handler.

In my project, I created a single entry point servlet for all UI related processing. When I needed to implement the first Task Queue I created another entry point servlet for the queues/crons and then coded inside new handlers.

In general, your app design would be looking similar to 
UI ---> Servlet Entry Point 1 ---> Generic Business Logic Handler ---> Specific Business Logic Handler --> System Services Handler ---> System Services

Instead of UI, now we have Queues/Crons calling the system, but generally, as was in my case, the cron was calling code that was more 'internal', for example, send-mail is implemented as a queued task which needs to directly call the System Service Handler bypassing two business logic layers. Similarly, ftp-today's-transactions is a cron that needs to directly call System Services bypassing the business logic layers.

**It makes sense to NOT directly call System services from servlet entry point 1, just because you happen to have it at hand and configured in web.xml. It makes more sense to create another entry point for queues and crons which are more 'internal'. 
The code then resides in the next level class (called Handlers, sometimes) And you can continue to maintain the hierarchy of layers if you are using packages to enforce it.**

You will then not feel bad about calling something sys level directly from servlet level as this will be a specifically secure and separate access interface *defined* to be calling direct.

Just to make it more intuitive, my two servlets are called

1. Thin - Thin Http Interface on NudeBusinessObjects [All BOs extend this, and there is a non Http interface]
2. Thiq - Thiq Http Interface on Queues

Thin just ensures the required parameters are present and passes to handler. It always calls com.mybusiness classes which in turn call com.mysystem classes if they need to.

Thiq has more code, needs secure credentials even on automatic, does more complicated validations and generally has defined high level behaviour for failures across crons/tasks. It always calls com.mysystem classes.

Just my two cents. It isn't too big a thing and if you only keep one entry point and achieve the same effect by writing things in handlers, or even servlets, it doesn't cause end of the world. It just looks ugly when you make an architecture diagram.